# How to find which line throws an exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, telerik

How to know that which line throws an exception in c# code.
I facing Selection Out of range exception directly on browser, so i can't detect where is the problem.
I try debugging many times but can't find where is the problem.
[image] 
Please help me to solving this.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/argumentoutofrangeexception-from-telerik-web-ui-radcombobox-performdatabinding() https://www.google.com/search?q=telerik+radcombobox+performdatabinding+argumentoutofrangeexception

Comment: You can stop at breakpoint at the last line of your code and compare the arguments you are passing with Telerik documentation

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio for debugging your server code, check the Exception Settings (if they are not visible go to the menu `'Debug' -> 'Windows -> 'Exception Settings'` and they should appear in the lower right by default) and make sure that the debugger is set to break on the relevant exceptions - in your case I would check the `'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'` tree, specifically the `'ArgumentOutOfRangeException'` there (but I usually enable the whole tree).

With this setting enabled on your next debug session, the visual studio debugger should break where the exception is thrown and show you a popup with details.

Answer (score 0):

- Have try catch for the whole code block.
- Mark break point on catch.
- So that you find from where it is throwing the exception.